# habarta typescript plugin unable to load class

Tags: java, gradle, plugins

I'm having a problem with the [habarta typescript generator](https://github.com/vojtechhabarta/typescript-generator), tried all versions from 2.7. to latest. Here's the gradle buildscript

```
generateTypeScript {
    jsonLibrary = 'jackson2'
    classPatterns = [
        'com.foo.**'
    ]
    excludeClasses = [
        'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository'
    ]
    excludeClassPatterns = [
        'java.io.Serializable',
        'com.foo.**Repository',
        'com.foo.**Builder',
        'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.**',
        'java.lang.Compareable',
        'org.bson.types.ObjectId'
    ]
    outputFile = 'build/customers.d.ts'
    outputKind = 'global'
    namespace = 'Customers'
    optionalProperties = 'all'
    customTypeMappings = [
        'java.time.LocalDateTime:string',
        'org.bson.types.ObjectId:string'
    ]
}
```

The error is

`Unable to load class 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository'.`

The class that could not be found is on the classpath, compiling the project works fine. Omitting the class either in excludeClasses or excludeClassPatterns doesn't make a difference.

None of the classes that should be converted (rules from classPatterns + excludedClasses(Patterns)) implement ReactiveMongoRepository.

What am I doing wrong and how to solve this?

Stacktrace

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':generateTypeScript'.
> org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/ReactiveMongoRepository

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':generateTypeScript'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$ExecuteTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:246)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:136)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:201)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:192)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/ReactiveMongoRepository
        at cz.habarta.typescript.generator.Input.loadClasses(Input.java:150)
        at cz.habarta.typescript.generator.Input.fromClassNames(Input.java:136)
        at cz.habarta.typescript.generator.Input.fromClassNamePatterns(Input.java:131)
        at cz.habarta.typescript.generator.Input.fromClassNamesAndJaxrsApplication(Input.java:55)
        at cz.habarta.typescript.generator.gradle.GenerateTask.generate(GenerateTask.java:184)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:794)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:761)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:317)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:309)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:185)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:97)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
        ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository
        ... 52 more
```

build.grade:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath 'cz.habarta.typescript-generator:typescript-generator-gradle-plugin:2.8.449'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'cz.habarta.typescript-generator'

group = 'com.foo'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 10

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()

}


generateTypeScript {
    jsonLibrary = 'jackson2'
    classPatterns = [
            'com.foo.**'
    ]
    excludeClasses = [
            'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository'
    ]
    excludeClassPatterns = [
            'java.io.Serializable',
            'com.foo.**Repository',
            'com.foo.**Builder',
            'org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.**',
            'java.lang.Compareable',
            'org.bson.types.ObjectId'
    ]
    outputFile = 'build/customers.d.ts'
    outputKind = 'global'
    namespace = 'Customers'
    optionalProperties = 'all'
    customTypeMappings = [
            'java.time.LocalDateTime:string',
            'org.bson.types.ObjectId:string'
    ]
}

task copyTypescriptTypes(type: Copy) {
    from file('build/customers.d.ts')
    into file('/frontend/src')
}

task buildAndCopy() {
    dependsOn generateTypeScript
    dependsOn copyTypescriptTypes
    tasks.findByName('copyTypescriptTypes').mustRunAfter 'generateTypeScript'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.passay:passay:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.neovisionaries:nv-i18n:1.23'

    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-data-redis')
    implementation('org.springframework.session:spring-session-jdbc')
    runtimeOnly('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('io.projectreactor:reactor-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')

    compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.2.11"
    compile "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11"
    compile "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11"
    compile "javax.activation:activation:1.1.1"
}
```

Classes that fail:

```
public class UserData {
  @Id
  private ObjectId id;
  @CreatedDate
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
  private LocalDateTime createdAt;
  @LastModifiedDate
  @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
  @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
  private LocalDateTime updatedAt;

  private String email;
}
```

Error:

```
Unable to load class 'org.bson.types.ObjectId'.
```

Comment: Could you post the entire Gradle build file, and the entire exception stacktrace?

Comment: @LppEdd sure, done

Comment: Try excluding " org.springframework.** " under the excludeClassPatterns property. Remove the excludeClasses block.

Comment: Tried it, same error unfortunately @LppEdd

Comment: I'll replicate your project.

Comment: Works fine here. Could you maybe publish somehow your com.foo classes? I really suspect you have some sort of dependency on that class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the answer seems to be you **have** a dependency on that `ReactiveMongoRepository` interface.

Trying out your project setup, without depending on `ReactiveMongoRepository`, running the `generateTypeScript` gives a clean build.

However when depending on that interface, the error matches what you posted (see below).
Extending the `ReactiveMongoRepository` and then marking it as excluded does not work, and is a bit non-sense, if that is the case.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/ReactiveMongoRepository
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    ...
```

---

Obviously `org.bson.types.ObjectId` cannot be excluded as you're using it inside `UserData`.

To solve the Jackson and Bson errors, you just need to required them as dependencies.
As of now they're available only via transitive-dependency, which might be a repackaged version.

```
compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype', name: 'jackson-datatype-jsr310', version: '2.9.8'
compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'bson', version: '3.10.1'
```

Comment: It seems to ignore everything in excluded class patterns. I've posted a mongo document which holds ObjectId only, same error only for ObjectId now. Could you give it a try please?

Comment: I have triple checked that every dependency on ReactiveMongoRepository is in excludedClassPatterns

Comment: Note that ObjectId is both in excludedClassPatterns as well it has a custom type mapping

Comment: PPS... :-) Removing ObjectId leads to an error about localDateTime. Very strange

Comment: Works like this. Still it should ignore all files that end with **Repository inside the package. A bit counter intuitve. (Those are the excluded files that implement the Repository). Copying the documents to another package and using this works though

Comment: @bambam I'm eating now, so not at the computer. However I think this might have something to do with the syntax you're using to express the exclusion

Comment: Yeah, I'm currently checking.. Thanks a lot for your help. 
buon appetito :-)

Comment: @bambam just checked. Your exclusion pattern works! Inside customers.d.ts *Repository classes aren't included

Comment: Saw that in the docs, yeah. I'm currently checking some deeper, would be nice to get that back working since it's quite helpful (and allready worked in other projects)

Comment: @bambam let me know. This project is interesting indeed.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a similar error and the above does not help you, it could be that you accidentally included a semicolon, e.g.

```
<class>
    path.to.dto.MinimalSomethingDto;
</class>
```

If you replace the semicolon, it's fixed:

```
<class>
    path.to.dto.MinimalSomethingDto
</class>
```